# Individual row for each node field in a view

Tags: 7, views, entities

I'm trying to create a view of a node's fields, primarily a list of images and node references to be rendered with a [views slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).

The view has two fields listed, an image field and a reference. I'm showing fields, without default file wrappers, and formatting that with views slideshow. The slideshow settings doesn't have a grouping option, as it seems to provide more of skin styling, and cycling options.

My problem is each row is spitting back 2 items per row. Example, if I have a node with pictures: p1, p2, p3 and reference R1, R2.

The results of the view will be something like this:
P1, R1
P1, R2
P2, R1
P2, R3

And on. What I need is just a plain list of the images and references, not in a matrix like result, so something more like: P1, P2, P3, R1, R2.

I did take a look at the query that the view is using, which looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid, field_data_field_images.delta AS field_data_field_images_delta, field_data_field_images.language AS field_data_field_images_language, field_data_field_images.bundle AS field_data_field_images_bundle, field_data_field_images.field_images_fid AS field_data_field_images_field_images_fid, field_data_field_images.field_images_alt AS field_data_field_images_field_images_alt, field_data_field_images.field_images_title AS field_data_field_images_field_images_title, field_data_field_images.field_images_width AS field_data_field_images_field_images_width, field_data_field_images.field_images_height AS field_data_field_images_field_images_height, field_data_field_sia_image.delta AS field_data_field_sia_image_delta, field_data_field_sia_image.language AS field_data_field_sia_image_language, field_data_field_sia_image.bundle AS field_data_field_sia_image_bundle, field_data_field_sia_image.field_sia_image_nid AS field_data_field_sia_image_field_sia_image_nid, 'node' AS field_data_field_images_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_sia_image_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_images} field_data_field_images ON node.nid = field_data_field_images.entity_id AND (field_data_field_images.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_images.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_sia_image} field_data_field_sia_image ON node.nid = field_data_field_sia_image.entity_id AND (field_data_field_sia_image.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_sia_image.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.type IN  ('blog_post', 'sia_inline_slideshow')) AND (node.nid = '77603' ) ))
```

I ran that through mysql workbench to look at the results it is spiting back. Even with distinct, I'm getting multiple responses from one image field. It looks like the issue is there are multiple instances of field_data_field_[fieldname]*field*[fieldname]_nid. Each image also has a single incremented delta.

Question is, is there a way in views to just get the distinct values, or do I need to use the template system to override the output and remove the duplicates?

Comment: What kind of sorting do you need? Is it OK if all the references come first, then all the images, or vice versa? or do you need them more integrated?

Comment: @rooby Right now I don't think I need any sorting, so having images first followed by references would be fine.